# Gazebo grass/pavement plane flickering

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-camera, gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I built a simple model of outdoor environment using grass plane and pavement plane models (from DRC simulator [database](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/b36170c2460b/gazebo_models/environments?at=default)). My world file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.4'>
  <world name='default'>
    <light name='sun' type='directional'>
      <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      <pose>0.000000 0.000000 10.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000</pose>
      <diffuse>0.800000 0.800000 0.800000 1.000000</diffuse>
      <specular>0.200000 0.200000 0.200000 1.000000</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>1000.000000</range>
        <constant>0.900000</constant>
        <linear>0.010000</linear>
        <quadratic>0.001000</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <direction>0.500000 0.100000 -0.900000</direction>
    </light>
    
  <include>
    <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    <name>ground_plane</name>
    <pose>0 0 0   0 0 0</pose>
  </include>
  
      <physics type='ode'>
      <max_step_size>0.001000</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1.000000</real_time_factor>
      <real_time_update_rate>1000.000000</real_time_update_rate>
      <gravity>0.000000 0.000000 -9.800000</gravity>
      <max_contacts>20</max_contacts>
    </physics>
    <scene>
      <ambient>0.400000 0.400000 0.400000 1.000000</ambient>
      <background>0.700000 0.700000 0.700000 1.000000</background>
      <shadows>1</shadows>
    </scene>
  
    <state world_name='default'>
      <sim_time>0 0</sim_time>
      <real_time>0 207512</real_time>
      <wall_time>1372662656 276170409</wall_time>
    </state>
    <gui fullscreen='0'>
      <camera name='user_camera'>
        <pose>3.082640 -6.458740 2.425810 0.000000 0.367643 2.028200</pose>
        <view_controller>orbit</view_controller>
      </camera>
    </gui>
  
  <!-- road segment ******************************    -->  
  <include>
    <uri>model://pavement_plane</uri>
    <name>pavement_plane_0</name>
    <pose>0 0 0   0 0 0</pose>
  </include>
  
  <include>
    <uri>model://grass_plane</uri>
    <name>grass_plane_0_0</name>
    <pose>0 -1 0   0 0 0</pose>
  </include>
  
  <include>
    <uri>model://grass_plane</uri>
    <name>grass_plane_0_1</name>
    <pose>0 2 0   0 0 0</pose>
  </include>
  
  <include>
    <uri>model://grass_plane</uri>
    <name>grass_plane_0_2</name>
    <pose>0 1 0   0 0 0</pose>
  </include>
  
  <include>
    <uri>model://grass_plane</uri>
    <name>grass_plane_0_3</name>
    <pose>0 -2 0   0 0 0</pose>
  </include>
```

etc...

When moving camera in Gazebo GUI planes are somehow flickering - at some position it looks good but in some other there are "holes". Also images published by robot cameras are flickering too.

See [pict1](http://imageshack.us/a/img59/2025/ykfq.png), or [pict2](http://imageshack.us/a/img600/9702/y3p.png) (can't upload here because of karma).

I tried to downscale textures but it's same. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3510/gazebo-grass/pavement-plane-flickering/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Flickering in OpenGL is generally an indication that you have two faces which are very close together, close enough that they render to the same Z-buffer value.  Two instances of the same object at the same location will do it.

---

Originally posted by [John Nagle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/395/john-nagle/) with karma: 66 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1